# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. VUEJS 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an error when importing appsync settings for my project

the error

```
 error  in ./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/dist-es/getCanonicalHeaders.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:30)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|         const canonicalHeaderName = headerName.toLowerCase();
|         if (canonicalHeaderName in ALWAYS_UNSIGNABLE_HEADERS ||
>             unsignableHeaders?.has(canonicalHeaderName) ||
|             PROXY_HEADER_PATTERN.test(canonicalHeaderName) ||
|             SEC_HEADER_PATTERN.test(canonicalHeaderName)) {

 @ ./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/dist-es/index.js 2:0-60 2:0-60
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/dist-es/configurations.js
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/dist-es/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-es/S3Client.js
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-es/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/aws-appsync/lib/link/complex-object-link-uploader.js
 @ ./node_modules/aws-appsync/lib/link/complex-object-link.js
 @ ./node_modules/aws-appsync/lib/link/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/aws-appsync/lib/client.js
 @ ./node_modules/aws-appsync/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.85:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

in vue.config.js the configuration file I am using a loader but it does not work for me

```
 chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.module
      .rule('graphql')
      .test(/\.graphql$/)
      .use('graphql-tag/loader')
      .loader('graphql-tag/loader')
      .end();
```

info about project

package.json resume

```
    "aws-appsync": "^4.1.9",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "graphql": "^14.0.2",
    "vue-apollo": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-graphql-loader": "^1.0.2",
```

params exported

```
export default {
  "graphqlEndpoint": "https://secretEndpoint/graphql",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "authenticationType": "API_KEY",
  "apiKey": "secretKey"
}
```

in app.vue

```
import AWSAppSyncClient from "aws-appsync"
import VueApollo from 'vue-apollo'
import appSyncConfig from './AppSync'

const config = {
  url: appSyncConfig.graphqlEndpoint,
  region: appSyncConfig.region,
  auth: {
    type: appSyncConfig.authenticationType,
    apiKey: appSyncConfig.apiKey,
  }
}
const options = {
  defaultOptions: {
    watchQuery: {
      fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network",
    }
  }
}

const client = new AWSAppSyncClient(config, options)
const appsyncProvider = new VueApollo({
  defaultClient: client
})
```

in main.js

```
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  provide: appsyncProvider.provide(),
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

**can someone help me to solve this problem.
**

I tried different loader in the vue.config.js files but none worked for me.

try something like this:

install `npm i json-loader`

```
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
  
    config.module
      .rule('jsauto')
      .use('javascript/auto')
      .loader('json-loader')
      .end()
```

With this configuration, the error that I get is different:

```
 error  in (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.85:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node

Syntax Error: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)


 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.85:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js

Syntax Error: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed this npm package @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining ?
If not, install it
Looks like an optional chain operator ?. problem

Comment: I tried installing the libraries and adding the plugin configuration but it didn't work for me

Comment: Can you try to put this sentence in brackets?
（ unsignableHeaders?.has(canonicalHeaderName) ）
My guess

Answer (score -1):

It was resolved by updating the version of the vue CLI that I was using

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).